# How to get a friend's education and work history information using FBoauth module

Tags: authentication-authorization, social-network

Is there any way to get friend's education history and work history? I tried to send permission friend_education_histroy and friend_work-history on fboauth.fboauth.inc file. But I got an error.

How will I pass the permission to Facebook and get my friend's info?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your permissions to make sure that FB hasn't changed anything as they are notorious for changing their code. Here are the [Permissions Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

Comment: yeah i checked already..'select name,education,work from user WHERE uid IN (select uid2 from friend where uid1=($user)) '.now i get friends info in corephp using facebook phpsdk.but i cann't convert this in drupal fboauth module.this module doesn't allow my code to getting friend education history and work history.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check the required permission on the setting page "en/admin/config/people/fboauth" under user advance permission setting.